# StructureMap with Quartz.Net not working

Tags: c#, structuremap, quartz.net

I am trying to implement Quartz.Net with StructureMap but the job is not getting triggered. My code looks like this.

```
public class SampleRegistry : Registry
    {
        public SampleRegistry()
        {
            Scan(x =>
            {
                x.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                x.WithDefaultConventions();
                x.AddAllTypesOf<IJob>().NameBy(c => c.Name);
            });
            For<IJobFactory>().Use<StructureMapJobFactory>();

            For<ISchedulerFactory>().Use(ctx => new StdSchedulerFactory());
            For<IScheduler>().Use(delegate(IContext ctx)
            {
                var scheduler = ctx.GetInstance<ISchedulerFactory>().GetScheduler();
                scheduler.JobFactory = ctx.GetInstance<IJobFactory>();
                return scheduler;
            });
        }
    }
```

The StructureMapJobFactory code looks like

```
public class StructureMapJobFactory : IJobFactory
{
    private readonly IContainer container;

    public StructureMapJobFactory(IContainer container)
    {
        this.container = container;
    }

    public IJob NewJob(TriggerFiredBundle bundle, IScheduler scheduler)
    {
        return (IJob) container.GetInstance(bundle.JobDetail.JobType);
    }
}
```

The Sample Job looks like

```
 public class SendMailJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IMailService _mailService;

    public SendMailJob(IMailService mailService)
    {
        _mailService = mailService;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _mailService.SendMail();
    }
}
```

And the JobDetails

```
IScheduler scheduler = ObjectFactory.GetInstance<IScheduler>();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create(typeof(Code.Services.SendMailJob))
                                   .WithIdentity("sampleJob", "group1")
                                   .Build();

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                                         .WithIdentity("sampleTrigger", "group1")
                                         .StartNow()
                                         .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInSeconds(1).RepeatForever())
                                         .Build();


        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: After you call ScheduleJob, do you keep a reference to the scheduler? You need to make sure you keep a reference to the scheduler in order for it to keep running.

Comment: @jvilalta The problem I am having is IMailService is not injected into the constructor. If I call a job without any dependencies it works fine.

Comment: Is the issue that the job is getting triggered and you're getting a null reference exception in the execeute method or is the job not getting created at all and you get an error when you try to schedule it?

Comment: @jvilalta, I was able to figure out the issue. My IMailService was using HttpContext directly and that was causing the exception when the job was fired and not running the code to send emails.

Comment: Adding link to the StructureMap implementation for Quartz.net https://gist.github.com/Saanch/2c1e63b225ff5d13d145